# Gui is update before function's execution complete

Tags: android, model-view-controller, class

I have two activities in which I am using the same code for add, update and delete with an `AlertDialog`. Now I want to write that code in class file and then access that function from my  activities. I also want the `UI` to be updated only after the function completes execution.

I have tried calling the function of class file like

```
Contact_update c=new Contact_update(context);
c.delete();
myactivityfunction_gui_update();
```

But the problem is that before the function is completed the execution of the  `myactivityfunction_gui_update();` is getting called so I can't get updated result in my activity. Can anybody tell me what is the correct way?

Comment: simply call you gui update function **after** whatever it is you are doing

Comment: does the delete function use a separate thread?

Comment: not thread but use the database class and phone's database

Comment: do u mean call the myactivityfunction_gui_update();
 function from delete function? where i have written the code for delete contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asynctask.
Keep all the add update function in a class like this,

```
public Class A{

   A(Variables){
  }
  int method A(){
   return int data
   } 
 .
 .
 .
 int method Z(){
return int data
}

}
```

// In Your Activity

create asynctask function as

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {




            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
// dismiss progress bar and call your GUi update function call here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

//Show progress bar             
super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

// Your time consuming function call
int c=new A.method()

                return null;
            }


        }.execute();
```

Comment: but if after calling the function as you have said int c=new A.method() in post execute, we need to update the listview that is fillup by database query not by the function return data.then at where that listview update function will write?
in post execute

Comment: If you are using list view, create a function in your class A which will return you the values for in ArrayList<T> T may be Class or datatype, Call this function in do in background, now in the postExecute method just initialize the adapter for ListView with the returned data, and reset the ListView.....